# How can I delete an image with Eye of Gnome / EOG?

Tags: 17.10, photo-management, eog

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 and I wonder how I can delete an image with Eye of Gnome / EOG, I press <kbd>del</kbd> keyboard button, but nothing happens. Also there is no option for delete on the menu:

[image: EOG UI, compressed menu has no delete]

My EOG version is:

```
$ sudo apt show eog
Package: eog
Version: 3.26.1-0ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Comment: On 3.28.2 and Arch Linux, pressing Del works for me.

Comment: @muru Yes, it should work, but it is not working for me. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/edit.html.en) says:

> To delete a picture that you don't want any more, right-click the picture and select Move to Trash.

Comment: For some reason I didn't try right-clicking

Answer (score 1):

I don't reproduce on eog 41 Ubuntu 21.10, clicking the "Delete" key immediately deletes the image without any confirmation.

Also, the right click menu mentioned at https://askubuntu.com/a/1039691/52975 shows that "Delete" is a shortcut for "Move to Trash", so we understand it is not actual deletion.

One thing to note is that it does not delete corrupt images for some reason, it only works if the image was properly decoded.

Comment: `shift+delete` delets permanently

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case I had 2 delete keys on the keyboard. Try the other delete key, not the one on the number keypad (Del)... the one next to insert, home, end buttons (Delete).